# Why is answer (3615) being offered a bounty from Community even though it has a negative score?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This [answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/3615/5253) about aggressively handling people smoking in public has a negative score. I don't know what the score was when the bounty was first offered, but as of right now, the users seem to agree that it is a problematic answer (myself included). Yet the Community has offered a 500 rep bounty for it being "exemplary."

I am ignorant of how the Community offers bounty, so could someone explain what exactly happened here? Also why it happened?

Comment: For the record, when I first saw the bounty, the answer was at 0 score.

Answer (score 15):

It wasn't originally offered by Community. It was offered by a user who has since had their account removed (user11886). Community user doesn't offer bounties and has no reputation to give.

With no one to actually award it, it will not be awarded to anyone unless someone posts a new answer and earns a score of at least two, in which case, the highest voted answer posted during the bounty period will receive half the bounty amount. These are the standard [bounty awarding rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: The accepted answer has a positive score, and the bounty says: *@Vylix answer was exemplary and is worthy of a bounty.* Will that bounty actually get reassigned if a new, good answer is given? It seems to me that the [removed] user has already chosen the recipient.

Comment: That's not how bounties work. You can't assign and awardee when posting it. That's just text. The system isn't aware of the selection. Only answers posted during the bounty period can be automatically awarded the bounty.

Comment: "If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)." That *is* how bounties work. You can choose to award it to any answer (except your own) immediately after posting.

Comment: No. You have to wait 24 hours. When the bounty is awarded, the bounty status ends. "A bounty can be awarded 24 hours after the bounty was started. You can award the bounty to any answer posted by anyone else, even an answer that has already been awarded one or more bounties (including by you)."

Comment: It is indeed a fundamental flaw that "reward an existing answer" is a reason to award a bounty, and yet you still have to wait 24 hours to give the award.

Comment: @corsiKa Actually, I prefer to wait until the very end, so that the answer I'm about to award gets more upvotes.

Comment: Still, if I'm just trying to reward someone, I shouldn't be forced to wait 24 hours. If you want to wait the full week, that's up to you. But if someone has impressed me and I feel they deserve more fake internet points for it, I shouldn't have to remind myself to go back. (Usually, the bounty system reminds me "Don't forget to award a bounty!")

Comment: @corsiKa It's sort of irrelevant here? It's not site-specific, it's a network policy. There are [already requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268362/waiting-24-hours-to-reward-an-existing-answer-is-completely-illogical) to remove the wait time if the reason selected is "reward existing"...

Comment: @Catija Well, it is relevant here in the sense that any site features are fully applicable to any meta those features exist on. Although truth be told, there's a marvelous discussion to be had on the matter that these comments are too narrow to contain, and I wouldn't expect it to change as a result of a few comments anyway. That'd be weird.